# Import the EPSG:7775 projection without PROJ.4 to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, epsg

I wanted to define the [EPSG:7775](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::7775) projection in QGIS but it has no field for PROJ.4. Everywhere I've seen that you can import a projection with PROJ.4. How do I import this?

I am trying to do [this](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_queries.html) (some basic spatial analysis) for the area specified (Uttar Pradesh) in EPSG:7775.

Comment: Note the tutorial you link to is obsolete, use the [QGIS 3 tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_queries.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to import/create a custom projection.  QGIS understands EPSG:7775

You can set your project to use this CRS with File->Project Properties->CRS
[image]